# What is the point of having both an "Authorization Grant" and an "Access Token" in Oauth?

Tags: security, oauth, https, authorization, access-token

I'm reading this article on Digital Ocean, and their explanation of Oauth is confusing to me. See the diagram below.

I don't understand why the Client needs to obtain an `Authorization Grant` in order to obtain an `Access Token` in order to access the protected resources. Why not just skip either the `Authorization Grant` or the `Access Token`? What is the point of having both? It doesn't seem to make anything more secure having both.

[image: Oauth 2.0]